# Class "SpoiledCar\FrontOfficeBundle\Entity\Modele" is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

hello everyone so this is my problem i got this error
  Class "SpoiledCar\FrontOfficeBundle\Entity\Modele" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
can anyone help me . thanks in advance i'm stucked here for about 5 hours

```
<?php

namespace SpoiledCar\FrontOfficeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="modele")
 */
class Modele
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * Many Features have One Product.
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Marque", inversedBy="modeles")
     * @JoinColumn(name="marque_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $marque;

            // ...
    /**
     * One Product has Many Features.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Voiture", mappedBy="modele")
     */
    private $voitures;
    // ...


    public function __construct() {
        $this->voitures = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     * @return Modele
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }
}
```

Comment: No one can help you without posting any code showing what you've done!

Comment: here's the code sorry for that  ;)

Comment: Can you show the code how you are using the `Modele` class? ANd specifically where the error message is coming from. We won't be able to help you unless you show enough information!

Comment: i just tried to do this php app/console doctrine:generate:entities SpoiledCarFrontOfficeBundle:Modele and i got this error

Comment: [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                          Class “SpoiledCar\FrontOfficeBundle\Entity\Modele” is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Comment: i want to add this class to te database but i have a problem in mapping

Answer (score 0):

How about running:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities SpoiledCar/FrontOfficeBundle/Entity/Modele
```

Based on you comments, seems like that's what you should run.

Also the folders `SpoiledCar/FrontOffice/Entity` needs to exist.

---

**EDIT #2**

Can you move your Entity Modele under:

```
AppBundle/Entity
```

And then run:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/Modele
```

To see if that works.

Comment: Is `SpoiledCar/FrontOffice/Entity` under your `src` folder? Normally Enitities are under `src/AppBundle/Entity`.

Comment: yes the path is correct there is something else i don't know what

Comment: See my second edit. I want you to try it to see if that works. This is just to see if it works only.